# Making autocomplete search faster in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, autocomplete, indexing

I have implemented an auto-complete search on my website using ajax autocomplete control.It uses web service which returns results from database. 
I have a stored procedure which searches for all text values in all columns of all tables for this purpose. 
The problem here is results taking long to show up in autcomplete control.
I have also applied indexing on the most frequently searched table columns, but that to didn't help much. Can this be because of the load on the server, since the server is not a dedicated one. If not how can I fetch the results faster?

Comment: duplicate question :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447377/asp-net-super-fast-data-search-for-autocomplete-please-guide-me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always optimise the queries to load data faster and use server side caching to cache the data.

Also on UI I would recommend you to use [jQuery autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) plugin

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript"
        ];
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
    </script>
```